# how to use "MovableText"?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found this class on api documentaion(http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/1.2.5/classgazebo_1_1rendering_1_1MovableText.html)

Its description said "description: This create create a billboarding object that display a text."
(https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e8f7b58b28a8fc88dfd3480c7a6ea76e7c7032a9/gazebo/rendering/MovableText.cc?at=gazebo-current-prerelease_2.2.0)

So , I imaged that my gazebo window would be like this ([http://imgur.com/inihTnQ](https://imgur.com/inihTnQ)).

Because this class is under the namespace"rendering",

I thought "MovableText" should be used in system plugin

Then, i built a system plugin like this (http://pastebin.com/mTtTVR8s)

But ,nothing happened!

could you tell me how to use this class correctly,thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8263/how-to-use-%22movabletext%22?/) by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 80 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2015-03-17**:
Looking into the API, maybe you should call the Load function as well at first.

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-03-18**:
hi,thank you for your advise, but after adding "text.load("AA","BB","Monospace",10)",  still nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found MovableText on ogre website(http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/MovableText)

and It does work !

That's what I need!

[http://i.imgur.com/MTH7i0d.png](https://i.imgur.com/MTH7i0d.png)

---

Originally posted by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) with karma: 80 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can see an example of `MovableText` being used [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/ca50f7f3cec40166e31b97bb66f5f1ff5c8e688d/gazebo/rendering/ApplyWrenchVisual.cc?at=apply_force_dialog#cl-121).

Since `rendering::MovableText` inherits from `Ogre::MovableObject`, you need to attach it to the `Ogre::SceneNode` of a Gazebo `rendering::Visual`. Something like this for example:

```
// Get the user camera
rendering::UserCameraPtr userCamera = gui::get_active_camera();

// Create a visual and add it to the camera's scene
rendering::VisualPtr visual;
visual->Load();
userCamera->GetScene()->AddVisual(visual);

// Create text, Obs: Font size is in meters
rendering::MovableText *text;
text->Load("__TEXT_OBJECT__", "text displayed", "Arial", 0.1);

// Create a node for the text
Ogre::SceneNode *textNode = visual->GetSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode("__TEXT_NODE__");
textNode->attachObject(text);
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-03-19**:
hi ,there, thank you for your advice .I revised my code (http://pastebin.com/7egMy7fJ).But It still can not show the text :(  , thank you

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-03-20**:
I updated the answer with an example, I haven't tested it though. Note that the font size is in meters, you're using 200 in your code, so maybe if you zoom out a lot you can see the text.

**Comment by [Zheng yo chen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/800/zheng-yo-chen/) on 2015-03-24**:
thank you , but I have runtime error.. :(

**Comment by [neet](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47636/neet/) on 2021-07-05**:
Hi, could you share the sample code by GitHub? The link has died :(((